# How can I covert a PDF created by PDFLatex (Kile) to its .tex file?

Tags: macos, pdf, latex, osx-mavericks, file-conversion

Unfortunately I have lost my .tex file, and I have changed a lot of things in my resume.  I was wondering if there might be a way to convert a PDF file created with Kile and LaTeX back into a .tex file?  I am using OSX Mavericks, so any tool will be really appreciated. I did a quick survey on web and saw some comments that it's not possible. Hopefully there's a way in my special case.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I think it's never possible to convert a PDF back to it's sources...

Comment: Hi Daniel, does that hold for the PDFs which were created from a .tex file as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the file with Lyx. As it is a WYSIWYG processor it may work.